# Cannot locate file from parent directory(s)

Tags: 14.04, package-management, find, aws

Apologies if this isn't the appropriate place for this question

I'm running an Amazon Lightsail VPS with an Ubuntu 14.04 image and trying to install various packages through `npm`. One particular package installation fails because it can't locate a file at

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/cairo.pc
```

When I check the directory, the file definitely exists and has the expected contents and appropriate permissions

```
user@hostname:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu$ stat -c "%a %n" ./pkgconfig/cairo.pc
  644 ./pkgconfig/cairo.pc

user@hostname:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu$ locate cairo.pc
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/cairo.pc
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/pangocairo.pc

user@hostname:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu$ cat ./pkgconfig/cairo.pc
  prefix=/usr
  exec_prefix=${prefix}
  libdir=${prefix}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
  ...
  //etc. - excluded for brevity
```

But interestingly, when I try to locate the file via `find` it states that the file cannot be found from outside of its directory, even though it's listed in the output (shortened for brevity)

```
user@hostname:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig$ find cairo.pc
  cairo.pc

user@hostname:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig$ cd ..

user@hostname:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu$ find ./pkgconfig cairo.pc
  ./pkgconfig
  ./pkgconfig/gio-2.0.pc

  ...
  ./pkgconfig/gmodule-2.0.pc
  ./pkgconfig/cairo-ft.pc
  ./pkgconfig/cairo.pc
  ./pkgconfig/xau.pc
  ./pkgconfig/cairo-svg.pc
  ./pkgconfig/gmodule-export-2.0.pc
  ...

  find: `cairo.pc': No such file or directory
```

This lead me to believe that there's some quirk with the file in the filesystem or permissions that are preventing it from being found (like a bad cache or something), as opposed to an error with the package/package manager, but I honestly have no idea where to begin as a linux newbie

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Please run this instead `find ./pkgconfig -name cairo.pc`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your running that command the wrong way, this:

```
find ./pkgconfig cairo.pc
```

should have been:

```
find ./pkgconfig -name cairo.pc
```

In your case your asking `find` to search in two paths `./pkgconfig` and `cairo.pc`(which is a file not a directory). If you had done:

```
find ./pkgconfig ./another_folder -name cairo.pc
```

It would find `cairo.pc` in those two locations, but in your case your searching in just `pkgconfig` folder so `find ./pkgconfig -name cairo.pc` is the right command to use.

Please see `man find` for how to use the find command and [here](https://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/linux-unix/find-how-search-multiple-folders-directories-unix) for more explanations.

Comment: Thanks! this answers my question but unfortunately doesn't solve my problem - It must be an issue with the package then. It claims it can't find the file in the search path but checking the environment variable it seems to be looking in the right place. In any case I imagine it's outside the scope of this site

Comment: It's not since it's running on Ubuntu, but that's a different question in itself.